# SwiftUIでTabの個数を可変に色々なViewを表示させたいのですがどうすれば可能でしょうか？

Tags: swift, swiftui

### やりたいこと

Tabに複数のタイプのViewを表示させたいのですが、その複数のタイプのViewを持つ`tabList`に複数のタイプのViewを持たせる方法がわかりません。
コメントアウトした、１つの種類のみならできるのですが、2種類以上追加しようとするとうまくいきません。

### 考えうる方法1

`CustomTab1`と`CustomTab2`にあたらに作成した同じクラスを継承させ、tabListを新たに作成したクラスの配列として宣言する。

※実装方法がわかりません。

### 考えうる方法2

tabListをViewの配列として宣言する

※これもまた実装方法がわかりません。

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTab1 : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("CustomTab1")
    }
}

struct CustomTab1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomTab1()
    }
}

struct CustomTab2 : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("CustomTab2")
    }
}



struct CustomTab2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomTab2()
    }
}


struct Tab: View {
    //var tabList = [CustomTab1(),CustomTab1(),CustomTab1(),CustomTab1()]
    var tabList = [CustomTab1(),CustomTab2(),CustomTab1(),CustomTab2()]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(1..<self.tabList.count) { i in
                self.tabList[i].body
                    .tag(i)
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Tab\(i)")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Tab_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Tab()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、やりたいことは下記だと思います。

[How to have a dynamic List of Views using SwiftUI の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681450/1979953)

上記を参考に、ご質問に合うように書き換えたものを下記に載せます。

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTab1 : View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("CustomTab1")
  }
}

struct CustomTab1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    CustomTab1()
  }
}

struct CustomTab2 : View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("CustomTab2")
  }
}

struct CustomTab2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    CustomTab2()
  }
}


struct Tab: View {
  var tabList: [Any] = [
    CustomTab1.self,
    CustomTab2.self,
    CustomTab1.self,
    CustomTab2.self
  ]

  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      ForEach(0..<tabList.count) { index in
        self.buildView(
          types: self.tabList,
          index: index
        )
      }
    }
  }

  func buildView(
    types: [Any],
    index: Int
  ) -> AnyView {
    switch types[index].self {
    case is CustomTab1.Type:
      return AnyView(CustomTab1().tag(index))
    case is CustomTab2.Type:
      return AnyView(CustomTab2().tag(index))
    default:
      return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
  }
}

struct Tab_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    Tab()
  }
}
```